# In jetpack what is setContent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Android Development and Kotlin

I notice this function?   **setContent { }**  , I want to know what is this block. is it a function !?  why it is invoked with curly braces.

the code is bellow

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Text("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advanc

Comment: yes we can take the lambda function out but we cannot add the name to it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. [`setContent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).setContent(androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionContext,kotlin.Function0)) is a function that takes a lambda, and this is a trailing lambda syntax like in the linked question.

Comment: thanks a lot shirakhilc . i got it now ..because it is the only one parameter.